# mod_rewrite issue

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and my url is as follows:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/189-9544737-0616922?%5Fencoding=UTF8&node=10
```

On myphp.php

```
var_dump($_GET): array(3) { 
  ["q"]=>  string(19) "185-8676848-3133633" 
  ["_encoding"]=>  string(4) "UTF8" 
  ["node"]=>  string(2) "10" }
```

Any ideas?

regards,

Comment: "Any ideas?" - You might want to tell us what you expect first.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `B` modifier:

> Apache has to unescape URLs before
>   mapping them, so backreferences will
>   be unescaped at the time they are
>   applied. Using the B flag,
>   non-alphanumeric characters in
>   backreferences will be escaped.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [B,L,QSA]
```

Comment: What do you want to see on the PHP side?  The entire URL and query string in a single variable?